# How to Create Table-valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to create a View from the following query, the view give me the result but I am unable to save the view, getting error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Declare'.

Latter find out that I can not make view due to variable in the query. Will someone help me to create the table valued function from the following query, please note that be easy on me new in SQL.

Many thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @NextDate DateTime
SET @NextDate =
(SELECT TOP 1 att.attend_date
FROM Attendance att
WHERE att.ID_Employee=att.ID_Employee and
att.attend_date > att.attend_date
ORDER BY att.attend_date ASC) 
SELECT emp.*,
@NextDate AS NextDate,
   COALESCE(@NextDate, GETDATE()) AS Next123,
   DATEDIFF(DAY, COALESCE(@NextDate, GETDATE()), att.Attend_Date) AS DifferenceDays,
   CASE WHEN ((att.attend_date + 90) < COALESCE(@NextDate, GETDATE())) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END AS Day90Credit,
   CASE   
WHEN ((att.Attend_Date + 90) < COALESCE(@NextDate, GETDATE())) THEN        att.Attend_Date + 90
   ELSE att.Attend_Date + 365
   END AS CreditDate,
       att.attend_date,
       att.attend_date +90,
   CASE WHEN (
   CASE   
   WHEN ((att.attend_date + 90) < COALESCE(@NextDate, GETDATE())) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END) = 0 AND (              
CASE WHEN ((att.Attend_Date + 90) < COALESCE(@NextDate, GETDATE())) THEN     att.Attend_Date + 90
   ELSE att.Attend_Date + 365
   END) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OR (                   
   CASE   
   WHEN ((att.attend_date + 90) < COALESCE(@NextDate, GETDATE())) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END) = 1 THEN 1
   ELSE   0
   END AS TotalCredit
   FROM
   attendance att
          INNER JOIN employees emp ON att.ID_Employee= emp.Employee_ID
```

Comment: Your query where you set `@NextDate` will never return a record - you have the line `att.attend_date > att.attend_date` something can never be bigger than itself so `@NextDate` will always be `NULL`. Throughout your query you use `COALESCE(@NextDate, GETDATE())` so you are always just using `GETDATE()` - so you can remove the variable completely, replace it with `GETDATE()`, and create a view after all

Comment: Please google and learn about the CREATE FUNCTION command in SQL Server.